# How can I add "tags" to a search field using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some tags (`tagbutton`) in a table, each tag has its own id, what I want to achieve is when the user clicks on the tag, a hidden input is created in the form with the value of the div (or tag) that has been clicked on. I also want the clicked div to be copied in the `tagselected` div. 
I have no idea how to do that on jquery. Thank you very much in advance for your help.

```
 <table> <tr>


         <td>   <div class="tagbutton" id="jazz"> Jazz </div> </td>

         <td>        <div class="tagbutton" id="classical"> Classical </div> </td>

         <td>        <div class="tagbutton" id="R&B"> R&B </div> </td>

</tr> </table> 


<div id="tagselected"> </div>

<form> <input type="text"> <button ="submit"> Submit </button> </form>
```

Here is the javascript function that I have to copy the div, however when I clicked on it the entire table is copied

```
$('#jazz').click(function () {

      $('.tagbutton').clone().insertAfter("#tagselected");

    });
```

Comment: @ManoloSalsas true, but we also like to provide constructive feedback

Comment: Sorry, but you have only posted a simple HTML markup, show us what have tried in js/jQuery

Comment: Sorry, I'm posting what I have it right now

Comment: From help center: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is wrong:

```
$('#jazz').click(function () {

  $('.tagbutton').clone().insertAfter("#tagselected");

});
```

The problem with this code is that you are retrieving all the items with class `tagbutton` on the whole page. If your click function is on the item you want then you should be able to just use `this` to access the clicked item.

so something like :

```
  $(this).clone().insertAfter("#tagselected");
```

This code is not tested and is just the simple change of the initial jQuery selector.

I assume the problem you have with the hidden fields is the same - that you were selcting all tags instead of just the one you clicked so hopefully this will solve that problem too.